# Are there any rules preventing the transfer of runes on intelligent weapons?

Tags: crafting, pathfinder-2e, intelligent-magic-items

Are there any rules preventing transferring runes on intelligent weapons, besides [Item Agency](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=1092)?

Comment: Are you asking about adding and removing runes, or just removing?

Comment: All of that. I mean adding, removing and transfer runes. I didn't see anything preventing that, except taht the intelligent weapon might not activate the new runes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes (with a caveat)

The [rules on specific magic weapons](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=767) state (CRB, p 600, emphasis mine):

> These weapons have abilities far different from what can be gained by simply etching runes. A specific magic weapon lists its **fundamental** runes, which you can upgrade, add, or transfer as normal. You can’t **etch** any **property** runes onto a specific weapon that it doesn’t already have.

Presumably, an intelligent weapon is a specific magic weapon, and thus *cannot have any **property** runes added to it*. There doesn't seem to be anything preventing their removal, though. It's worth discussing options with your GM.